# How can I subscribe to an event passed as a parameter to a function?

Tags: c#, events

I am trying to add a listener to an event through a function.

```
event Action ExampleEvent;

void AddListener(Action emitter, Action receiver)
{
     emitter += receiver;
}
```

Then somewhere I call it like this:

```
AddListener(ExampleEvent, () => Console.WriteLine("Example event received"));

ExampleEvent?.Invoke();
```

But there is no output. I don't see what's missing.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ref` keyword like this.

```c#
event Action ExampleEvent;

void AddListener(ref Action emitter, Action receiver)
{
     emitter += receiver;
}

// Usage
AddListener(ref ExampleEvent, () => Console.WriteLine("Example event received"));

ExampleEvent?.Invoke();
```

Because `Action` instances are like a pointer (or a list of pointers) to a function(s) and they will be passed by value as a parameter. So, in order to pass them by reference, you need to use the `ref` keyword.